# Subtract rows from two dataframes based on index value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'Value': [10, 9, 8, 10, 99 , 88],
    'Day' : [1,2,3,4,1,2]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name' : ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'Value': [1,2,3,4],
    'Day' : [1,2,3,4]
})
```

I would like to subtract the values in `df1` with the values in `df2` based on the day and create a new dataframe called `delta_values`. If there are no entries for the day then no action should occur.

To explain further: `B` in the name column only has values for day 1 and 2. `df2` should subtract its values associated with day 1 and 2 with `B`'s values for day 1 and 2, but since `B` has no values for day 3 and 4, no arithmetic should occur. I am having trouble with this part.

The output I am looking for is

[image: output]

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing better comes to somebidy's mind, here's a correct but not very elegant solution:

```
results = df1.set_index(['Day','Name']).unstack()['Value']\
             .subtract(df2.set_index('Day')['Value'], axis=0)\
             .stack().reset_index()
```

Make the result look like the expected output:

```
result.columns = 'Day', 'Name', 'Value'
result.Value = result.Value.astype(int)
result.sort_values(['Name', 'Day'], inplace=True)
result = result[['Name', 'Value', 'Day']]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can merge the two DataFrame's on the `Day` column and then subtract from there.

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='Day', suffixes=('', '_y'))

print(merged)

  Name  Value  Day Name_y  Value_y
0    A     10    1      C        1
1    A      9    2      C        2
2    A      8    3      C        3
3    A     10    4      C        4
4    B     99    1      C        1
5    B     88    2      C        2

delta_values = df1.copy()
delta_values['Value'] = merged['Value'] - merged['Value_y']
print(delta_values)

  Name  Value  Day
0    A      9    1
1    A      7    2
2    A      5    3
3    A      6    4
4    B     98    1
5    B     86    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make do with either `map` or `merge`. Here's a `map` solution:

```
delta_values = df1.copy()
delta_values['Value'] -= delta_values['Day'].map(df2.set_index('Day')['Value']
                                                ).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Value  Day
0    A      9    1
1    A      7    2
2    A      5    3
3    A      6    4
4    B     98    1
5    B     86    2
```